# Two subprojects A and B, A depends on B and checks for features present in B

Tags: cmake, dependencies, botan

I'm trying to create a CMake project that integrates 2 sub-projects, specifically [botan](https://botan.randombit.net/) and [rnpgp](https://www.rnpgp.com/). The build system of rnpgp is CMake-based, botan uses a Python configure script to generate a Makefile.
The problem is that during the CMake run rnpgp checks for features in botan, so it requires a compiled botan library. But, botan doesn't get built until I actually call `make`, which I can't do because rnpgp fails to configure because botan isn't built yet.

What's the right way to specify such a dependency in CMake?

Comment: do you have some code that you can share and tell us where the problem is?

Comment: What I basically want to do is a cmake based build of rnpgp on a system where botan is not installed. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CMake's [`execute_process()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) to run the botan Python script and run `make` during the CMake configure stage. This way, the botan library will be built and available to reference when running the mpgp CMake:

```
# Run the Python script to configure the botan Makefile.
execute_process(COMMAND
    python ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/botan/configure.py
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
)
# Run 'make' from the botan directory where the 'Makefile' was created.
execute_process(COMMAND
    make
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/botan/build"
)
```

This is a rough example of what it could look like. You may have to modify the paths a bit to match where you have botan on your system, and where botan generates its build artifacts (i.e. location of the Makefile).